# If a "Get Records" element fails to find records, does it count as an interview?

Tags: soql, visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, subflow

*#1 Disclaimer: if anyone have an opinion about this data structure, please let me know.*

So, after looking at the picture of the Schema Builder, here's the scenario:

The Instrumento Contratual (IC) object is integrated to DocuSign. This integration allows the users to submit a DocuSign evelope only once. So, this object is there to bulkify the Espelho object into the IC.

As you can see, the Espelho object has multiple child objects. I've decided to do this because all of those processes needs to be approved in the Espelho object. Since it's a Master-Detail relationship, the user submit only the Espelho object, and its approval also approves (and locks) the child records.

*#2 Disclaimer: I've tried to kill this Espelho object and approve those child objects in a mass-approval AppExchange app, but even the company's directors wouldn't allow me.*

Now, to the flow. I have a RT that is triggered when the IC is signed (the DocuSign app changes the IC status). Then the flow needs to look at all the Espelhos related to the IC, and get the ID's of all child records the Espelhos have. The only way I know how to do this, since there are different objects, is to have a Get Records element to each object. So, I have two questions:

**Question #1: is there a better way to find these ID's?**

**Question #2: if a Get Records element does not find any record, does it still count as an interview?**

[image]

Comment: A Flow Interview in a record-triggered flow is the triggered record (i.e. when the IC is DML'd). The Get Records within the flow are part of the interview